# Return unmatched values from SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Table Data

```
| line  | exclusionflag
+-------+----------------
| aaaaa | false
| bbbbb | false
| ccccc | true
| eeeee | true
| ggggg | false
| iiiii | true
```

Query:

```
select * 
from table 
where line = 'aaaaa' AND exclusionflag = false -> works

select * 
from table 
where line = 'bbbbb' AND exclusionflag = false -> works
```

But how to make this following query work or a variant of it?

An item NOT present in the table.. say 'ddddd'

```
select * 
from table 
where line = 'ddddd' AND exclusionflag = false`
```

Now returns nothing since there is NO row with ddddd and exclusionflag = false understood!

But I would like to return the rows 'ccccc', 'eeeee' and 'iiiii' row

In other words the 'ccccc', 'eeeee' and 'iiiii' rows   excludes results which contain 'ccccc', 'eeeee' and 'iiiii'  but if I pass any other value it must return THAT row

Is this possible?

Comment: Sorry. I have added sql and postgres only now.

Comment: I don't follow the logic.  Perhaps you need more examples.

Comment: So... if you search with exclusionflag = false, then it should return either the matching row (if found), or all rows with exclusionflag = true (if not found). Is that the logic you want?

Comment: What happens when you search with exclusionflag = true?

Comment: @TheImpaler 'ddddd' is NOT in the database records at all. So When I run select * 
from table 
where line = 'ddddd' AND exclusionflag = false` it must return  'ccccc', 'eeeee' and 'iiiii'  as the result. I'm looking for an equivalent query like above.

Comment: What's the logic behind the exclusionflag? What if you search for true? I fear, we don't understand your logic yet... Please describe why c, e, i should be returned in your case.

Comment: I think you want to show exact result if condition return row. But if condition do not return any row then you want to show records which are exclusionflag='true'

Answer (score 0):

The query can be (with a value `ddddd` that doesn't exist):

```
with q as (select * from t where line = 'ddddd' not exclusionflag)
select * from q
union all
select * from t where exclusionflag and not exists (select * from q);
```

Result:

```
line   exclusionflag 
------ ------------- 
ccccc  true          
eeeee  true          
iiiii  true
```

But then if you run the same query with a value that does exist (`bbbbb`):

```
with q as (select * from t where line = 'bbbbb' and not exclusionflag)
select * from q
union all
select * from t where exclusionflag and not exists (select * from q);
```

You get:

```
line   exclusionflag 
------ ------------- 
bbbbb  false
```

See running examples at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pqEZYXoYFyDkk2KJYaKYY1/1).